# How to get the first and second word from a string in jquery?

Tags: javascript

I have a checkbox having value attribute as shown below :

```
<input type="checkbox" class="skis checkbox" name="skis" value="hi?hello?Good">
```

When I am clicking this particular checkbox i want to get the value of this checkbox separately in three different JavaScript variables as hi, hello, Good and should check with ? delimiter in jQuery. Can anyone say how to do this in JavaScript ?

Comment: what did your try. If you would have googled would have got thousands of search results for splitting a string based on a delimiter.

Comment: Search around `split` method

Comment: Why did you unaccept mate? I was the one who first answered. Not fair buddy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this javascript code.

```
 $(function(){

      $('input.checkbox').on('click',function(){
          var val=this.value.split('?');
          var first=val[0];
          var second=val[1];
          var third=val[2];
          debugger;
      });

});
```

Answer (score 3):

You **don't need** jQuery for this. To split the string, you can just use [`.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) function with the parameter being the question mark. All the values will be stored as an **array** and you can access the first two words using the array index.

```js
$(function () {
  $("input").click(function () {
    var values = this.value.split("?");
    console.log("First word: " + values[0]); 
    console.log("Second word: " + values[1]);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="skis checkbox" name="skis" value="hi?hello?Good">
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) function to split string on every delimiter:

```html
<input
    type="checkbox"
    class="skis checkbox"
    name="skis"
    value="hi?hello?Good"
    onClick="console.log(this.value.split('?'))"
/>
```